# Scan code of Keyboard in c#

Tags: c#

I'm doing a project in c#. I want to catch the data of scan code of the keyboard.
I have used the MapVirtualKey() function. But with this function, the keyboard have translated from scan code into ascii code, then we use this function to translate from ascii back to scan code.
I want to know how to catch the scan code of the keyboard, before it translate into the ascii code, that mean when i press a key, i will get make code. When i release, i will get break code.
For example, press key 'A' i will get "1E" , release i will get "9E" (makecode and breakcode of scan code set 1).
Thanks all.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?
why not just wrap MapVirtualKey()?

Comment: I want to catch the raw data that the keyboard send, that means the scan code. MapVirtualKey() just translated between scan code and ascii code, not catch the code. When you press the key, the keyboard will immediately send the scan code, after that the driver will change it into the ascii code. What I want is getting the scan code when i press the keyboard, not the translated scan code from ascii code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Microsoft's information on [Raw Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Here is a article on how to [Using Raw Input from C# to handle multiple keyboards](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard). (Has code Samples)

This is an OS level (WINAPI) function. It seems that you need to **Registering for Raw Input**, then you can **Perform a Standard/buffered Read of Raw Input**.